# How do I find all possibillities for Androids "Theme XML Style"?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-theme

The following file defines the base style used by my application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="Snapchat" parent="????" >
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/Snapchat_violet</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/Snapchat_blue</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/Snapchat_blue</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/Snapchat_white</item>
    <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/Snapchat_yellow</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/Snapchat_grey</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I want to use a standard theme as the parent to inherit from, but I can't find a listing of all standard themes and their corresponding xml names/paths.

I'm sorry if this is a newbish question, but I just can't find it in the android documentation.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#PlatformStyles You are welcome!

Comment: Ok im really dumb, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

check out following links it will help you

**Theme.xml**

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml

**Style.xml**

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple styles per file using  tag but each style will have its name that uniquely identifies the style. Android style attributes are set using  tag as shown below −

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
  <style name="CustomFontStyle">
  <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
  <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
  <item name="android:capitalize">characters</item>
  <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
  <item name="android:textSize">12pt</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>/>
```

The value for the  can be a keyword string, a hex color, a reference to another resource type, or other value depending on the style property.
Using Styles
Once your style is defined, you can use it in your XML Layout file using style attribute as follows −

```
  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/text_id"
  style="@style/CustomFontStyle"
  android:text="@string/hello_world" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

To implement a custom theme create or edit MyAndroidApp/res/values/themes.xml and add the following −

```
<resources>
 ...
 <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="android:style/Theme">
 <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffff0000.    </item>
 </style>
  ...
 </resources>
```

In your AndroidManifest.xml apply the theme to the activities you want to style −

```
 <activity
 android:name="com.myapp.MyActivity"
 ....
 android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme"
 />
```

Your new theme will be applied to your activity.

You can also have a look at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_styles_and_themes.htm

Answer (score 0):

See [style](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html), [stylable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html) and [attr](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html).